# Which is the Swift equivalent of isnan()?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nan

Which is the equivalent of `isnan()` in Swift ? 
I need to check if some operation results are valid and delete those invalid like x/0
Thanks

Comment: the result of division by 0.0 is NOT .nan but .inf

Answer (score 142, accepted):

It's defined in the [FloatingPointNumber](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/FloatingPointType/) protocol, which both the [Float](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Float/) and [Double](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Double/) types conform to. Usage is as follows:

```
let d = 3.0
let isNan = d.isNaN // False

let d = Double.NaN
let isNan = d.isNaN // True
```

If you're looking for a way to make this check yourself, you can. IEEE defines that NaN != NaN, meaning you can't directly compare NaN to a number to determine its is-a-number-ness. However, you can check that `maybeNaN != maybeNaN`. If this condition evaluates as true, you're dealing with NaN.

Although you should **prefer using `aVariable.isNaN`** to determine if a value is NaN.

---

As a bit of a side note, if you're less sure about the classification of the value you're working with, you can switch over value of your `FloatingPointNumber` conforming type's `floatingPointClass` property.

```
let noClueWhatThisIs: Double = // ...

switch noClueWhatThisIs.floatingPointClass {
case .SignalingNaN:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.SignalingNaN)
case .QuietNaN:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.QuietNaN)
case .NegativeInfinity:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.NegativeInfinity)
case .NegativeNormal:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.NegativeNormal)
case .NegativeSubnormal:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.NegativeSubnormal)
case .NegativeZero:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.NegativeZero)
case .PositiveZero:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.PositiveZero)
case .PositiveSubnormal:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.PositiveSubnormal)
case .PositiveNormal:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.PositiveNormal)
case .PositiveInfinity:
    print(FloatingPointClassification.PositiveInfinity)
}
```

Its values are declared in the [FloatingPointClassification](http://swiftdoc.org/type/FloatingPointClassification/) enum.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer works but when I first saw it I wasn't exactly clear because of the example and i didn't know that NaN is an acronym for `"not a number"`.

Here's an example from Apple for anyone who isn't clear:

[image]

```
let x = 0.0
let y = x * .infinity // y is a NaN because .infinity is not a number

if y.isNan {

    print("this is NaN") // this will print
} else {

    print("this isn't Nan")
}
```