# Swift zero divided by zero gives NAN

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing some calculation using Swift. I understand that in Swift, 0/0 gives NAN (not a number) instead of 0. Is there anyway for it to return 0 instead?

```
for x in 0..<n {
for y in 0..<n {
if(B[0,y,x]==NAN) {B[0,y,x]=0 }    //use of undeclared identifier 'NAN'

println("\((Float)B[0,y,x])")

}
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want that?

Comment: In your own code? Or in some library? If in your own code, you can add an `if`.

Comment: Because this code involves doing certain engineering calculation. I want the zero to be return back to show the user is zero instead of nan. Because users using this program, do not know what does nan means...

Comment: Not to overstate what may not be obvious, but zero divided by zero is *not* zero, it's infinity/undefined, which is why you get `NaN` (or a crash) in most languages. If you want to transform this particular corner case into some different output for the user, check for the zero denominator and bail out returning whatever you want instead.

Comment: Will this if statement code works?

Comment: what do you mean check for zero denominator and bail out returning whatever you want instead? How do i do it?

Comment: if statement NAN does not work... It gives an error of "use of undeclared identifier 'NAN'"

Comment: Just ran into this. That's just straight-up wrong. It's a Swift bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NaN is defined in `FloatingPointType` protocol.
[Which is the Swift equivalent of isnan()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351377/which-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-isnan)

Then, if you want zero, how about using [Overflow Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37)?

```
let x = 1
let y = x &/ 0
// y is equal to 0
```

**[UPDATED]**

You can define custom overflow operator like this.

```
func &/(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float {
    if rhs == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return lhs/rhs
}

var a: Float = 1.0
var b: Float = 0

// this is 0
a &/ b
```

Comment: c[x] = B[0,y,x] &/  B[0,x,x]

Comment: c[x], B[0,y,x] are type float. The overflow operator give me an error of type 'Float' does not conform to protocol  '_IntegerARithmeticType'

Comment: Can someone tell me what &/ is doing?

Answer (score 6):

good answer from @bluedome, in case you want this as an extension and\or have any errors there is an answer

```
infix operator &/ {}

extension CGFloat {
    public static func &/(lhs: CGFloat, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if rhs == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        return lhs/rhs
    }
}
```

then you can divide by zero

```
let a = 5
let b = 0
print(a &/ b) // outputs 0
```