# How to check for a Not a Number (NaN) in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

The following method calculates the percentage using two variables.

```
func casePercentage() {
        let percentage = Int(Double(cases) / Double(calls) * 100)
        percentageLabel.stringValue = String(percentage) + "%"
}
```

The above method is functioning well except when cases = 1 and calls = 0.
This gives a *fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN*

So I created this workaround:

```
func casePercentage() {
    if calls != 0 {
        let percentage = Int(Double(cases) / Double(calls) * 100)
        percentageLabel.stringValue = String(percentage) + "%"
    } else {
        percentageLabel.stringValue = "0%"
    }
}
```

This will give no errors but in other languages you can check a variable with an .isNaN() method. How does this work within Swift2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351377/which-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-isnan

Comment: @Cosyn I read that link but it doesn't make any sense to me as a n00b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "force unwrap" the optional type using the `!` operator:

```
calls! //asserts that calls is NOT nil and gives a non-optional type
```

However, this will result in a runtime error if it *is* `nil`.

One option to prevent using `nil` or 0 is to do what you have done and check if it's 0.

The second is option is to `nil`-check

```
if calls != nil
```

The third (and most Swift-y) option is to use the `if let` structure:

```
if let nonNilCalls = calls {
    //...
}
```

The inside of the `if` block won't run if `calls` is `nil`.

Note that `nil`-checking and `if let` will *NOT* protect you from dividing by 0. You will have to check for that separately.

Combining second and your method:

```
//calls can neither be nil nor <= 0
if calls != nil && calls > 0
```