# == with Double arguments with unexpected behaviour

Tags: swift

Is this behavior expected?

```
let k = [0.0, .nan]
let r = k.map {
    [$0.isNaN,
     $0 == .nan, // Why this is ALWAYS false?
     $0 == $0]   // Why this is NOT ALWAYS true?
}
```

If yes, why?

Comment: Compare [Which is the Swift equivalent of isnan()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24351377/2976878) – a comparison with `.nan` always returns false, including `Double.nan == .nan` (which actually breaks the semantic requirement of `==` being an equivalence relation).

Comment: This is how the equality with `NaN` is defined in IEEE 754

Comment: There actual question here is why is .nan == .nan false. As in the case `$0 == .nan` when `$0` is `0.0` we expect that to not be equivalent to `.nan`. When it is .nan how would you define two `.nan's` being equivalent, just because it is not a number doesn't mean it is the same not a number. In the second case when `$0` is `0.0` it is true, when `$0` is `.nan` it is false for the same reason as previously stated.